# How to access the instance of a component from another component?

Tags: vue.js, components

In a certain component A, I want to access `$refs` property (not sure if "property is the right term) of another component B. To do that, I need access to the *instance* of component B in order to obtain its `$refs`, sort of like that: `instanceOfB.$refs`

But how to access instanceOfB, that is, how to access instances of components?

For the record, the code I want to execute injects a new instance of a certain component (Button) into some sibling component (no parent-child relationship), so it's more complicated than simply passing a variable:

```
import Button from 'Button.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(Button)
var instance = new ComponentClass()
instance.$mount()
this.$refs.container.appendChild(instance.$el)
```

Comment: Without seeing some code of what you are trying to do it's a bit hard to give a specific answer but from what I understand you can only use a $ref to pass something to a child component and as the docs say, refs are "only meant as an escape hatch for direct child manipulation". You might want to look at props for passing information to a child and events like $emit for passing to a parent. If your components don't have a parent child relationship you would need a vuex store.

Comment: Even in a Vux mutation I'll need to access the instance of the component, so the same problem is the same. I can't show code as my question is too general (not every question requires or is informed by code)